# ¿Por qué eclipse no reconoce las librerías externas que he importado?

Tags: java, eclipse, java-import

Resulta que estoy trabajando en un proyecto de java en eclipse, y necesito dos .jar que ya tenía guardados. Los he añadido al classpath, y los he copiado a una carpeta lib dentro de la carpeta del proyecto. Ahora los archivos me aparecen en eclipse en la parte de referenced libraries, pero cuando hago un import de alguna de las librerías, me sigue dando el error "The type xxx is not accessible". No entiendo por qué no funcionan los import, si en teoría la librería está en orden.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Para que eclipse tome en cuenta las importaciones, estas se debe agregar a una biblioteca a la ruta de clase del proyecto:

Haga clic con el botón derecho en el proyecto:

> Build Path > Configure Build Path

Abra la pestaña **Libraries** y luego haga clic en:

> Add JARs (si el JAR se encuentra en la carpeta del proyecto)

o en:

> Add External JARs (si el archivo JAR se encuentra en otro lugar)

Por último debes actualizar el proyecto en eclipse usando:

> File -> Refresh

Entonces todas tus importaciones funcionarán perfectamente.